# Изменение аргумента функции внутри функции и возвращение нового значения

Tags: c#

У меня имеется некий статичный класс. В нем имеется функция типа void. На вход задаются три аргумента. Если я изменю в функции аргумент изменится переменная в основной программе которую я использовал как аргумент моей функции, или же нужно использовать функцию типа Vector3( мне нужен вектор скорости ), чтобы непосредственно возращать нужное значение?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Сначала вспомним, как передаются аргументы в методы. Аргументы ссылочных типов передаются копированием ссылки на объект, аргументы значимых типов -- копированием значения.

```
void Foo(string s, int i)
{
    s = "new text";
    i = 42;
}

string s = "text";
int i = 0;
Foo(s, i);
```

После вызова метода `Foo` значения переменных не изменятся, поскольку внутри метода мы поменяли *копию* ссылки `s`, и *копию* значения `i`.

"Исправить" эту ситуацию можно, применить модификатор [`ref`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/14akc2c7.aspx):

```
void Foo(ref string s, ref int i)
{
    s = "new text";
    i = 42;
}

string s = "text";
int i = 0;
Foo(ref s, ref i);
```

Вот теперь значения после вызова `Foo` изменятся.

При этом *содержимое* объекта ссылочного типа мы можем изменять внутри функции (при условии, что имеем доступ к этому содержимому) и без этого модификатора:

```
void Bar(List<int> list)
{
    list[0] = 42;
}

var list = new List<int>() { 0 };
Bar(list);
```

После вызова метода в списке будет находиться значение 42.

---

Поэтому ответ на первый вопрос зависит от того, какого типа аргумент вы передаете и как именно его меняете.

Дальше, насчет возвращаемого значения. Да, в идеале ваша функция должна возвращать новое значение (она ведь функция :)). Потому как в идеале функции не должны менять состояния аргументов. Этому есть несколько причин, главная из которых -- это упрощение понимания и отладки кода.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, сейчас попробую.

Answer (score 2):

Это зависит от того, переменную какого типа Вы передаете. Если это ссылочный тип, то вызов функции, меняющий состояние этого объекта изменит состояние объекта и снаружи метода. Кроме того, у параметра функции может быть модификатор `out` или `ref`, который также позволит изменить состояние объекта снаружи функции.

Лично я предпочитаю, так называемые, чистые функции - функции, вызов которых не меняет состояния программы. Поэтому я бы рекомендовал Вам изменить сигнатуру метода таким образом, чтобы она возвращала новый объект.